# Use HashMap in java for bracket pairing?

Tags: java

I am trying to use HashMap to match the orders of bracket pairs using the index + 1, but I failed to properly order a bracket inside another bracket? If I had these as an input:

```
()[[]]
```

then I would expect the output to be

```
1 2
3 6
4 5
```

I have tried using this line,

```
mapping.put(input.substring(0, i).lastIndexOf("[") + 1, i + 1)
```

but the output is

```
1 2
4 6
```

Can anyone please help me fix the code? I am a beginner, please don't go hard on me. Thank you!

Comment: Can you show a [mcve], rather than just _one_ line of code?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure why you want a HashMap there. Usually such task is done by using a stack. You just iterate through all characters of the string. Each time you find an opening bracket (parenthesis, brace) you put it (and its position) on the stack. Each time you find a closing bracket (parenthesis, brace) you check the top of the stack, it should contain the opening bracket of the same type. If it's not, then you have unbalanced string, like `([)]`. Otherwise you know the position of the opening bracket (it was also stored on the stack) and can print it together with the closing bracket position.

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to get at in my now deleted comment :) - I just forgot about the potentially unbalanced input which is a good  catch.

Comment: Hey! I am actually using stack exactly the way you said it, but I have no idea how to use stack to identify the index of the brackets from the original string. Is there a method specifically for that? Thanks!

Comment: You should put the index of the found bracket on the stack as well. For example, you can create a helper class which will just have 2 fields - a character and an integer. You'll make a stack of objects of this class. Then when you find an opening symbol you put on the stack a new instance of this class and initialize it with the found opening symbol and the current position in your string. When you find a closing symbol you pop() the object from the stack and get the position of the opening bracket from its integer field.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should be using a Stack, which will be more easy for you too.

If you don't know what a Stack is, i'll explain it to you:

A Stack uses the LIFO pricipal, which stands for "Last in, first out", which says that the last thing you put into the stack will be the first thing that you get out of it. You can perform actions like pushing a item to the stack or popping one of or just check what's on the stack.

So maybe just take a look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-for-balanced-parentheses-in-an-expression/ -> read it and you will understand it :)

I hope this helps you, if not so, then just tell it, i will try to help you then :)

Comment: Maybe take a look at a java implementation

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain the positions of the opening and closing brackets using a stack. So, when you encounter an opening bracket, put the position and bracket into the stack and for each 'i' check if its the closing bracket, and if it is, then simply pop out the opening bracket's position and put it into your result map.

e.g.

```
    static class Pair {
        char bracket;
        int position;

        public Pair(char bracket, int position) {
            this.bracket = bracket;
            this.position = position;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String bracketSequence = "()[[]]";
        Stack<Pair> stack = new Stack<>();
        Map<Character, Character> charMap = Map.of(
                ')', '(',
                '}', '{',
                ']', '['
        );
        Map<Integer, Integer> mapping = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i=0; i<bracketSequence.length(); i++) {
            char bracket = bracketSequence.charAt(i);

            if (charMap.containsKey(bracket)) {
                char otherBracket = charMap.get(bracket);

                if (stack.size() == 0 || stack.peek().bracket != otherBracket) {
                    throw new Exception("Poorly formatted bracket sequence");
                }

                int position = stack.pop().position;
                mapping.put(position+1, i+1);
            } else {
                stack.push(new Pair(bracket, i));
            }
        }

        if(stack.size() > 0)
            throw new Exception("Poorly formatted bracket sequence");

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : mapping.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
public class ParenthesisDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String expression = "(5x7)[[]{}]";

        System.out.println("Input expression : " + expression);
        Map<Integer, Integer> parenthesisSequence = getParenthesisSequence(expression);
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : parenthesisSequence.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
        }

    }

    public static Map<Integer, Integer> getParenthesisSequence(String expression) throws Exception {
        Stack<Parenthesis> stack = new Stack<>();
        Map<Character, Character> parenthesisPair = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
        parenthesisPair.put(')', '(');
        parenthesisPair.put('}', '{');
        parenthesisPair.put(']', '[');

        Character parenthesis[] = { '{', '}', '[', ']', '(', ')' };
        Set<Character> validParenthesisSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(parenthesis));

        Map<Integer, Integer> parenthesisSequenceMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (int k = 0; k < expression.length(); k++) {
            char openParenthesis = expression.charAt(k);

            if (validParenthesisSet.contains(openParenthesis)) {

                if (parenthesisPair.containsKey(openParenthesis)) {
                    char closeParenthesis = parenthesisPair.get(openParenthesis);

                    if (stack.size() == 0
                            || stack.peek().type != closeParenthesis) {
                        throw new Exception("Invalid Expression");
                    }

                    int startIndex = stack.pop().index;
                    parenthesisSequenceMap.put(startIndex + 1, k + 1);
                } else {
                    stack.push(new Parenthesis(openParenthesis, k));
                }
            }
        }

        if (stack.size() > 0)
            throw new Exception("Invalid Expression");

        return parenthesisSequenceMap;
    }
}

class Parenthesis {
    char type;
    int index;

    public Parenthesis(char type, int index) {
        this.type = type;
        this.index = index;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Input expression : ({}[])[[]{}]
Output : 
1 6
2 3
4 5
7 12
8 9
10 11
```